# Records not showing up in report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

### Situation:

- Custom object 'MOP' has a master-detail to Opportunity
- Custom object 'Product Revenue Projection' has a master-detail to 'MOP'
- Custom report type Opportunities with MOP with Product Revenue Projections

I created a report of this type, and did not apply any filters at all.

[image: Report filters]
When I run this report as a **system administrator**, the report does not return all expected results. Eg. it should display this record, but it doesn't.

[image: Product Revenue Projection]
When I tried replicating this report in another org with a similar data model, it did not encounter this issue. Any suggestions where to look at/what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interaction with sfdc support solved the issue. The problem was due to an **incorrect role** being selected in the hierarchy for this report. This made the report to show only Opportunities of owners belonging to that role or subordinates.

[image: Report Role]